# Find and Replace child elements with JQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, find

I wish to make a find and replace operation (from '*' to '+') via JQuery in a list of child elements.

Sample code:

```
<div class="tt">
    <p>*Anything</p>
    <p>*Anything</p>
</div>
```

Desirable output:

```
<div class="tt">
    <p>+Anything</p>
    <p>+Anything</p>
</div>
```

This alerts me each 'p' tag changed:

```
$('.tt p').each(function(index) {
    var r=/^(<p>)(.)(.*)$/;
    var to_r='$1+$3';
    //var a=p.match(r);
    var a=p.replace(r,to_r);
    alert(a);
});
```

My JQuery skills end here. Thanks for any directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code:

```
$('.tt p').each(function(index) {
    var result = $(this).text().replace("*", "<b>+</b>");
    $(this).html(result);
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro. But, what if I needed to get the html code on order to change it? For instance, to achieve this output: `<p><b>+</b>Anything</p>`? I think that `$(this).html()` should do the job, but it's not...

Comment: Is the input in the same format ? like `<p><b>*</b>Anything</p>`

Comment: No, it is without the `<b>` tag, like this: `<p>*Anything</p>`. Thus the need of the regex I put in the beginning.

Comment: What do I have to do (probably in this line: `$('.tt p').each(function(index) {`) in order to work with the pure html code and not with the text rendered? This is because my real life sample is much more complicated than this. I simplified only to make the question simpler.

Comment: Well you can get the HTML inside every `<p>` by using `$(this).html();`. And to set a new HTML tag into the `<p>` you can use something like my edited code above..

Answer (score 2):

tt.each refers to the div, not to the p-tags. so try something like

```
$('.tt').find('p').each(function(){ $this.html('YourNewHTML or text')})
```

or use your regEx

Comment: Timo, sorry for this simple question but should I apply the regex in your solution?

Comment: it depends ;O). if you need it in the function, do is

Comment: ...do it. a simple replace("*", "+") without regEx might work, too. if you want to replace the same text with same new text in each p-tag, i think you don't need it